# How to implement an ePub reader for an iPad/iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, epub

I want to implement an ePub reader for the iOS platform. Please suggest any open source code for book flipping animation, bookmarks, font-size customization and single page view (without scroll bars).

Comment: Hi - the question has already been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359758/apis-for-supporting-epub-format

Comment: Yes. As per the answer I think we can display content of XHTML file in uiwebview. But I also want to split pages in a way that it doesn't have any scroll bar.

Answer (score 4):

As the previous article points out, there is no API that given an ePub will just display it -- you need to do some work:

1. Unzip the ePub
2. Read the manifest file and metadata file to find the xhtml documents to display
3. Load the xhtml documents into a UIWebView using a file:/// URL to the unzipped document

If you want to ensure that the documents don't hit the network you'll need to implement a custom NSURLProtocol and serve the bytes for the files yourself as file:/// allows cross domain access.

That will display the content just fine, but the "hard" part is moving between the documents (which usually represent a whole chapter). This is the work that iBooks and other apps do for you.

NOTE: For the UIWebView to display the content correctly, you have to ensure that the file has a .xhtml extension when using file:/// urls.  If you implement your own URL protocol handler, you need to make sure the protocol handler returns the correct xml content type for xhtml, namely:

application/xhtml+xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand the whole process but I have one query 
As you told "That will display the content just find, but the "hard" part is moving between the documents (which usually represent a whole chapter). This is the work that iBooks and other apps do for you."

Does iBook and other apps which can provide their reader which we can implement/use in our custom application??

Comment: @KanakVaghela no, at least nothing public.

Comment: @KanakVaghela Nir Levy is correct, there is nothing public.

Comment: @KanakVaghela how can we imapelement the landscape mode which is similar to iBook could you help me please

Comment: Upvoted for beautifully explaining the process.

Answer (score 4):

Use the ePub packaging format and an open-source reader for reference:

- [ePub3 Packaging](http://apex.infogridpacific.com/df/ePub3Packaging1.html)
- [fbReader Source](https://code.launchpad.net/fbreader)
- [Readium Source](https://github.com/readium/readium-sdk)
- [Calibre Source](https://code.launchpad.net/calibre)

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this steps :

**Source code:** [AePubReader](https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader)

---

**Implementation:**

**Step 1:** Create a view with a `UIWebView`

**Step 2:** Download an **EPUB** file and import into your project

**Step 3:** Unzip **EPUB** file to a subdirectory in your app's documents folder.

**Step 4:** Parse the `XML` file from directory `META-INF/container.xml`. If this file directory doesn't exist means, your EPUB file is invalid.

**Step 5:** In this `XML`, find the first "`rootfile`" with media-type `application/oebps-package+xml`. This is the OPF file for the book.

**Step 6:** Parse the OPF file (also XML)

**Step 7:** Now you need to know what the first chapter of the book is.

- Each in the element has an id and an href. Store these in an `NSDictionary` where the key is the id and the object is the href.
- Look at the first in the . It has an idref attribute which corresponds to one of the ids in (Step 7a). Look up that id in the `NSDictionary` and you'll get an href.
- this is the the file of the first chapter to show the user. Work out what the full path is (hint: it's wherever you unzipped the zip file to in (Step 3), plus the base `NSDictionary` of the OPF file in (Step 6).

**Step 8:** Create an `NSURL` using fileURLWithPath:, where the path is the full path from (Step 7c). Load this request using the UIWebView you created in (Step 1).

**Step 9:** You'll need to implement `forward / backward` buttons or `swipes` or something so that users can move from one chapter to another. Use the to work out which file to show next. Then the `XML` are in the order they should appear to the reader.

These step got referred from this [link](http://ideveloperworld.blogspot.in/2011/02/epub-reader.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use UITextView with pageview controller . (Specify your doubts , if any)